# How to align sliver app bar's flexible space bar title to all the way left?

Tags: flutter

I've the following UI to make in flutter where I am supposed to use the `SliverAppBar` or anything else that can get this done.

[image]

I can create this app bar but I can't figure out how to align the `heading` text and the `paragraph` text to the left. To the left at the same level as the leading back arrow icon.
Can someone help with this? This is the sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200,
              title: Text('Title text'),
              centerTitle: true,
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/04/42/conifers-1867371_640.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Big Heading',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Paragraph text',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(height: 1000),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: try setting `centerTitle: false`.

Comment: @gauravkumar that is for the app bar's title, not for the flexible space bar's title

Comment: now please try to use my code, I have updated my answer, and let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following modifications to your code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200,
              title: Text('Title text'),
              centerTitle: true,
              leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/04/42/conifers-1867371_640.jpg',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // Align to the left
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Big Heading',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Paragraph text',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 16.0), // Adjust padding as needed
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(height: 1000),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need. The content is supposed to be the part of the app bar itself. I've added the code to the question.

Comment: replace your code with this code.